# Check if number is between a range

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I'm trying to write a function that returns 1 if value is between input and 0 if not. Here's what I tried

```
def pixel_constraint(hlow, hhigh, slow, shigh, vlow, vhigh):
    """
    H - Hue:       (0-255) e.g red/cyan
    S - Saturation (0-255) e.g bright/not
    V - Value      (0-255) e.g black/white
    
    min = (hlow, slow, vlow)
    high = (hhigh, shigh, vhigh)
    if min >= high:
          return 1
      else:
          return 0
    """
```

Desired output:

```
    is_black = pixel_constraint(0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 10) 
    # Between (0 -> 255, 0 -> 255, 0 -> 10)

    is_black((231, 82, 4))
    >>> 1
    is_black((231, 72, 199))
    >>> 0
```

Comment: Wait, you're trying to write a function that returns a function? I don't think that's a good idea; if you want to have a function with the arguments already "baked in", we have [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) for that.

Comment: The code is a bit confusing - it looks like `pixel_constraint()` returns an `int` but you assign it to `is_black` and try to call it as a function?

Comment: pixel_constraint() returns an int (1 or 0), and then I check if the number 231 is in range 0-255, 72 is in range 0-255 and 199 in range 0-10 with is_black = pixel_constraint(0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 10) and then is_black((231, 72, 199)) returns 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your real intent is to have `pixel_constraint` return a function, this matches your desired output:

```
def pixel_constraint(hlow, hhigh, slow, shigh, vlow, vhigh):
    def f(pixel):
        h,s,v = pixel
        return int(hlow <= h <= hhigh and slow <= s <= shigh and vlow <= v <= vhigh)
    return f

is_black = pixel_constraint(0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 10) 
# Between (0 -> 255, 0 -> 255, 0 -> 10)

print(is_black((231, 82, 4))) #1
print(is_black((231, 72, 199))) #0
```